# What is the meaning of 女子力?

Tags: words, slang

What is 女子力?

I see it often recently, and understand that it does not worth discussing seriously about it. I know it is a stupid word. Just curious how people are interpreting it.

Comment: [This (girl power)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girl_power) seems relevant. Not sure how popular it was outside the UK. Is this question about the Japanese language? (not saying it's not, just asking)

Comment: +1 I read a Japanese article about it, but the concept was different than in my country. I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: 女子力...what a vague word... (Btw there's no such word as 男子力？^o^)

Comment: @Chocolate: Probably not because of the difference Dave mentioned. However, since the Japanese definition is different, I think the term 男子力 could be possible :)

Comment: Why don't we think why the word 女らしい (女らしさ) doesn't work in the same context? @Chris, 男子力 sounds like almost the same as 男らしさ.

Comment: @Gradius: I admit that I too think they are too similar. But I'm pretty sure that 女子力 refers to a "lifestyle" which makes the difference. Also, it appears that some people connect the outward appearance to 女らしさ, which is why a distinction is being made in the link Dave posted.

Comment: One difference is the diff. between 女子 and 女. Another is that 女子力 implies a kind of active mastery, where 女らしさ is more of an emergent trait. Like any other kind of power, 女子力 is a means to an end.

Comment: Oh yes~~ 女子力 sounds to me more powerful and positive than 女らしさ. And it sounds different from 女の力 or 女性の力, too.

Comment: 女子力(が高い・低い・アップetc.) sounds to me like-- how attractive and appealing (probably to men) and how capable and excellent (probably in work/business) a girl/woman is... (but this is only my personal impression.)

Comment: I mean, if consumers feel that a new word is more powerful and positive than other existing words, it means coining it was successful from marketing point of view.

Comment: Why do you need to apologize for discussing a "stupid" word?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Is this comment addressed to me? Which apology are you talking about?

Comment: "I know it is a stupid word. Just curious how people are interpreting it."

Comment: @AndrewGrimm And, where is the appology?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dave's explanation probably hits the nail on the head, but there might be something to add.

I had read that 女子力 is actually viewed somewhat as a "skill". (Obviously, this is taken in the context of the 心の力説 definition in Dave's link.) In this sense, the skill is to attract males and be popular around males through fashion and style. However, I read an article about a girl who cooked for a guy in order to "boost her 女子力" which might mean there are other things than just physical attractiveness involved. The underlying idea being that a girl with 女子力 will be able to indirectly attract males.

I'm not sure, but 女子力 seems linked to 女子会 which is another term for girls meeting together to talk about relationships, work, etc.

Answer (score 7):

According to [this explanation](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/keyword/%BD%F7%BB%D2%CE%CF), `女子力{じょしりょく}` refers to a woman's prowess with issues like fashion, make up, and style.

Which would be considerably different from the English "girl power", which is about a woman's particular ability to succeed in all realms of life, and implies women's ability to be just as good, if not better, than men.

Comment: I think 女子力 is generally used in relationship seeking also.

Comment: @Chris: And, apparently, through her underwear... according to the link.

Comment: I have seen the 仕事力説 and 心の力説, but the 下着力説 is very new to me! Where did that come from?

Comment: @Chris: Beats me :) This is a new word in flux, though, so it's still going where people take it.

Comment: What is 下着力・・・？"Power of underwear"??

Comment: @Chocolate: I'm not entirely sure, but I know it's had power over me now and again... ;)

Comment: @DaveMG へ～～(^m^)むふ♡